# Why aren't my queries and batch gets executed in parallel?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-trace

Based on the documentation for Objectify and Google Cloud Datastore, I would expect the queries and the batch loads in the following code to execute in parallel:

```
List<Iterable<Key<MyType>>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (...) {
  results.add(ofy().load()
      .type(MyType.class)
      .filter(...)
      .keys()
      .iterable());
}
...
Iterable<MyType> keys = ...;
Collection<MyType> c = ofy().load().keys(keys).values();
```

But the trace makes it look like each query and each entity load executes in sequence:

[image: Trace]

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this only happens when doing a cached get from Memcache. With similar code I see the expected async behavior for datastore_v3.Get/Put/Delete:

[image: datastore_v3.Get]
[image: datastore_v3.Put]
[image: datastore_v3.Delete]

It seems the reason for this is that Objectify doesn't use AsyncMemcacheService. Indeed, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/197) for this on the project page, and this can also be confirmed by checking out the source and doing a `grep -r AsyncMemcacheService`.

Regarding the serial datastore_v3.RunQuery calls, calls to ofy().load().type(...).filter(...).iterable() are 'asynchronous' in that they [return immediately](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#executing-queries), however the actual Datastore queries themselves get executed serially as the App Engine Datastore API [doesn't expose an explicitly async API for queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async#Async_Queries).